# Vodka / Gin production without a still, in the UK

Tags: vodka

So I have recently been looking into making my own vodka and/or gin. The laws around producing drinks like these in the UK don't see, very clear, so I was hoping someone here had more experience in it.

I know it's illegal in the UK to produce spirits with a still, without the proper license. It also appears to be illegal to produce spirits in any other way, within the UK.

The confusion comes around the use of the word "spirits". A spirit is usually an alcoholic drink that has been distilled, but if I was to make a base using water, sugar (6-7Kg roughly) and turbo yeast, then add my flavouring, to produce a drink similar to vodka or gin, would these still be classes as spirits, even at say 20-23%?

Thanks,
Carl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, regarding this question:

> I was to make a base using water, sugar (6-7Kg roughly) and turbo yeast, then add my flavouring, to produce a drink similar to vodka or gin, **would these still be classes [*sic*] as spirits, even at say 20-23%?**

**That is more of a legal question and is really outside of the scope of this site.**

Now, whether you can technically do it is a different question altogether (ie, **is it technically possibly to make a 20% - 23% beverage without distilling?**)

**tl;dr:** **Technically yes, but you really need to know what you're doing.** See below.

---

If your goal is just "20%-23% alcoholic beverage," you can accomplish that without any form of distillation by using a rigorous nutrient and step-feeding schedule along with an alcohol-tolerant yeast with low nutrient requirements, like Lalvin EC-1118 or K1-V1116. It's definitely not easy, but it is technically possible. It would also likely require quite a bit of aging to be palatable, as you would be pushing yeast well past its tolerance, leading to lots of fusel alcohols and other off-flavors.

Now, ***depending 100% on the legality of this in your region***, you could also look into ["fractional freezing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_freezing) (colloquially called "freeze distillation," even though you're not actually distilling anything)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_freezing):

> Fractional freezing is a process used in process engineering and chemistry to separate substances with different melting points. It can be done by partial melting of a solid, for example in zone refining of silicon or metals, or by partial crystallization of a liquid, as in freeze distillation, also called normal freezing or progressive freezing.

This is the process that was originally used in creating [applejack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applejack_(beverage)), and is used to some extent in creating [ice beers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_beer) such as an [eisbock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bock#Eisbock)

Be careful though. **Whereas distillation leaves impurities behind, fractional freezing concentrates them:**

> The danger of freeze distillation of alcoholic beverages, is that unlike heat distillation, where the methanol and other impurities can be separated from the finished product, **freeze distillation does not remove them**. Thus **the ratio of impurities may be increased** compared to the total volume of the beverage. This concentration may cause side effects to the drinker, **leading to intense hangovers and a condition known as "apple palsy"** (although this term has also simply been used to refer to intoxication, especially from applejack.)

This can be minimized or avoided if you have a clean fermentation free of fusels, have aged the fusels out of your beverage, or both.

Still, do not attempt the fractional freezing of a homebrewed alcoholic beverage without solid fermentation management techniques. Or if it's illegal in your country, I guess.

Comment: I was thinking of trying something like [this](http://stillspirits.com/pages/making-alcohol-without-distilling). 

The basic step by step is 20lt of water with 10.5Kg of dextrose (also seen 6-7Kg of sugar suggested), add turbo yeast and leave to ferment for 7-10 days at 18c-24c. Then add turbo clear and leave for 24 hours, before siphoning and adding flavouring to what should be around a 20% alcoholic base.

Comment: Theoretically, yes. Be mindful of that original gravity, though. A lot of yeast gets stressed when starting at gravities over 1.120 (~15.5% ABV), and can stall out or fail to start after 1.140 (~17.8%). The yeast will also be sterssed without proper nutrition. Stressed yeast = fusels = rocket fuel. That's why brewers will step-feed fermentables rather than front-load when trying to reach high ABV. Also, just fermenting sugar is going to give you [kilju](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilju), not vodka.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen kits sold online for whiskey and vodka like 
http://www.the-home-brew-shop.co.uk/acatalog/Prohibition_1_Gallon_Whisky.html

here is a youtube video of someone making one 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ET4BxmtYq_M

Comment: I think that may be my next step, I'd love to see about making a 5 gallons batch though and sticking it in my pressure barrel. The idea of having 40 pints of vodka on tap sounds appealing to me :)

Comment: I think a 5 gal batch would be possible, once you figure out yeast and nutrients....and having it on tap? just keep a case of redbull or monster on hand.